# Checkopenport - DB2 / shell script sample

Tags: db2, db2-luw, redhat

at DB2 startup we will check, whether the db2 port is in use.
In the client DB2 setup we have only one instance / server.
the port is always 50020 - for all servers.
our idea -
netstat -tunlp | grep ":50200"
and checking the return code
this works - but other ideas are welcome

Comment: Not sure  what your question is here.

Comment: I think they want to check if port `50020` is already in use before even _attempting_ to start their database. Adjust the command to `netstat -lnt` since you don't want to match UDP ports, and (ignoring the [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOCTOU) scenario) that should be good enough. Still, I wonder what'sthe harm when DB2 notices it cannot bind to its configured port, I would assume even DB2 has some error handling in place for this.

Comment: @ckujau - thks - good answer -  it is an automation task with ansible